# Does callable also gets executed in a thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice, callable

When we pass a runnabble to an executorService like

Future future = executorService.submit(runnable);

// As here executorService maps the object into instance of

new FutureTask(runnable);
and after that it executes the runnable using addWorker(runnable) -> which internally uses thread for execution.

As talking about callable

Future future = executorService.submit(callable);
// As here executorService maps the object into instance of

new FutureTask(callable);

How does JVM maps the callable and make it run concurrently. How does it uses the Thread to execute callable and maps the return result of the callable method in FutureTask instance.

because Thread has a very tight contract with run() method, How does JVM manages to call the call() method of callable if it uses a Thread to execute the callable.

Comment: Re, "...executorService maps the object [FutureTask]." I would not use the word "map" here. That word belongs mostly\* to the realm of functional programming and mathematics. If we say that "a maps to b," then we are implicitly saying that the _same_ a always\* maps to the _same_ b. But if you submit the same task to an executor service more than one time, the futures that you get back from it are in no sense "the same" as each other. Even if they both eventually yield the same value, they represent different events. They are completed at different times.

Comment: \* Of course, objects conforming to the Java `Map<k,v>` interface often are mutable, and mappings represented by `Map<k,v>` can be changed. But even so, that usage of "map" still is closer to the mathematical meaning than the way in which you are using it. At least, `map.get(k)` will continue to return the same `v` until you intentionally change the map by calling `map.put(k,...)`; but `executorService.submit(callableTask)` can _never_ return the same future object more than one time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the `Callable` gets executed by whichever thread grabs the task.

I think you're giving `Runnable` too much importance. The `Thread` class does implement `Runnable`, but that is not what makes the code multithreaded. That comes from Java starting an OS-level thread when you call the `Thread#start()` method (ignoring [virtual threads](https://openjdk.org/jeps/425)). After starting the thread, that new thread then calls the `Thread#run()` method. Any code that gets executed as a consequence of that `run()` method being executed is executed on said new thread (ignoring communication between threads).

By default, the `Thread#run()` method simply calls the `Runnable#run()` method on the `Runnable` instance given to the `Thread` when it was instantiated.

Now, you seem to be talking about `ThreadPoolExecutor`. Note that is only one implementation of `ExecutorService`, but I will focus on it, too. Internally, `ThreadPoolExecutor` creates one or more `Thread` instances and starts them when and as appropriate. These `Thread`s do not execute your submitted `Runnable` or `Callable` implementations directly. Instead, each `Thread` is created with an internal implementation of `Runnable`: [`Worker`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.java#L608).

Vastly simplified, this worker essentially does the following:

```java
while (!shutdown) {
    Runnable task = taskQueue.take();
    task.run();
}
```

Where `taskQueue` is an instance of `BlockingQueue<Runnable>`. When you submit a `Runnable` or `Callable`, they get put in this queue. This is how tasks are submitted by one thread but executed by another.

However, the `Runnable` or `Callable` you submit is not put in the queue *directly*. First it wraps your object in another that understands how to communicate a result back. In other words, an implementation of `Future`. But this `Future` still needs to also be a `Runnable`, which is where the `RunnableFuture` interface comes from. The implementation of this interface that is used by `ThreadPoolExecutor` is `FutureTask`, at least by default (you can override certain methods to return your own implementation). So, by default, it is a `FutureTask` that wraps your object that is actually put into the queue.

The `FutureTask` class internally wraps any `Runnable` in a `Callable`. Again simplified, it essentially does:

```java
// just the constructors

public FutureTask(Callable<V> callable) {
    this.callable = callable;
}

public FutureTask(Runnable r, V result) {
    this.callable = () -> {
        r.run();
        return result;
    };
}
```

<sup>**Note:** If you do `executorService.submit(runnable)` then `result` will ultimately be `null`.</sup>

Then the `FutureTask#run()` method (as [seen here](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.java#L307)) executes the `call()` method of the `Callable`. Once again vastly simplified, it essentially does:

```java
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        this.result = this.callable.call();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        this.error = ex;
    }
}
```

<sup>**Note:** This ignores the relatively complex code needed to synchronize the state of the task between threads, so that e.g., calls to `get()` wait for the result as needed (whether a return value or an exception). If you're interested in that, take a look at the implementation linked above.</sup>

Given the `FutureTask#run()` method is executed by whatever thread grabbed it from the task queue, the `Callable` will be executed by said thread.